# How to use http module with bluebird coroutine?

Tags: node.js, bluebird, es6-promise

How to use http with bluebird.
Following code returns nothing:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var co = Promise.coroutine;
http = Promise.promisifyAll(require('http'));

co(function*(){
    var resp = yield http.get("http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg").endAsync();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(resp.body));
})();
```

Comment: `http` doesn't follow the node node convention for callbacks (`function(err, res)`) so the promisification doesn't work, you should use `request-promise` for example.

Comment: I second the call to use `request-promise`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use request-promise

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var co = Promise.coroutine;
var rp = require('request-promise');

co(function*(){

   var resp = yield rp({uri: 'http://google.com'});

   console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));

})();
```